# На порте или на порту (в Сети)?

Tags: склонение, падежи

Здравствуйте, уважаемые эксперты русского языка! 
Ниже приведены цитаты из книги по сетевым технологиям. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно – «на порте» или «на порту»?

1. Чтобы коммутатор знал, какой порт использовать для передачи кадра, он должен сначала узнать, какие устройства существуют на каждом **порте**.
2. Когда коммутатор получает кадр **на порте**, настроенном в режиме доступа с назначенной сетью VLAN, он добавляет в заголовок кадра тег VLAN, заново вычисляет проверочную последовательность кадра (FCS) и отправляет этот тегированный кадр из магистрального порта.
3. Функция безопасности - Отключена **на порте**.
4. На рис. 2 показаны команды интерфейса командной строки Cisco IOS, необходимые для настройки функции безопасности порта **на порте** Fast Ethernet F0/18 коммутатора S1.

Спасибо.

Comment: А примеров с «на порту» нет?

Answer (score 4):

Сетевой порт - в порте, на порте - это уже [зафиксировано словарями](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82&all=x).

> 2. ПОРТ, -а; м. [англ. port] Мор. Герметически закрывающийся вырез в бортах судов для входа и выхода пассажиров, погрузки и выгрузки с
>      нижней палубы у транспортных судов и т. п. *Открыть порты*.
> 3. ПОРТ, -а; м. [англ. port от лат. porta - ворота, вход]. Устройство, с помощью которого к компьютеру могут быть подключены другие
>      устройства.
>
>    порт 2, -а, предл. в п**о**рте, мн. -ы, -ов (тех.)

Этот вопрос задавали и Справочной Грамоты.ру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]